# What is the name of this "plastic wire loop"?

Tags: components

Someone told me that it is called wire loop.
I want to buy it, but I could not find it using wire loop as keyword

[image]

Comment: You're getting good answers.  You can find a wide variety of this sort of thing by searching for "strain relief", too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that what you're looking for is a plastic *P clamp* (or *P clip*).

[image] from [here](http://www.keyelco.com/product.cfm/product_id/2663)

Comment: actually, the link you provided says "cable clamp"... it might be a good idea to provide that name in your answer also

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a P clip to me: -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would call that a "cable clamp".  If you google for that term, you should find pictures of a wide variety of cable clamps.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the name of the specific piece you are looking for (probably have multiple names, I think they are called `cable clamps`), looking through a electronic parts vendors catalog in the **Cable Management** section. That's where you will find them, especially through a gallery (or those big paper catalogs they love to send [and I **love to flip through**]). Most of all, you will find what *that* company calls them.